# Is addNotify appropriate to handle decorations?

Tags: java, swing

I have a decorated modal dialog which shows a screenshot aligned with desktop:

[image: Good]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ImageDialog extends JDialog {
    public ImageDialog() throws AWTException {
        Rectangle screenArea = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
                .getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenArea);

        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(image);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocation(100, 100);

        addNotify(); // XXX addNotify seems necessary. Better solution?

        Point p = new Point(getInsets().left, getInsets().top);
        SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, this);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(p);

        setModal(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        private BufferedImage image;
        public ImagePanel(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
        }
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new ImageDialog();
                } catch (AWTException ignore) {
                }
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't want to call `addNotify` since the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#addNotify%28%29) said so, but if I don't, the screenshot is not well aligned: <sub>(ah... those decorations around my dialog)</sub>

[image: Bad]

So, is this a case that I should call `addNotify`, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Probably not  but your other choices might be a WindowListener so you can determine when the window is resized, or even (as I would prefer), a ComponentListener on the ImagePane to detect when the component is resized, as it should be easier to detect the location of the component on the screen

Comment: Ps You should be calling super.paintComponent ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for pointing out the direction (I decided to use `windowOpened`) and the careless `super.paintComponent`.